# Tag information popup hidden behind edit form

Tags: bug, user-interface

When reviewing a pending edit *directly from the post*, hovering over tags causes the popup to show underneath the edit window.

Here's an example of what's displayed when hovering over [interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interface):
[image]